# How to set canvas preview language?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, localization

(currently trying on Xcode 11 Beta 7)

I want to pass an already localized string to Text() and see how it looks on canvas using ".environment(.locale, .init(identifier:"ja"))", but the preview is always set to whatever language that I have set on the scheme settings.

I know that it works if I pass a LocalizedStringKey directly, like Text("introTitle"), but I do not want to do that. Instead I want to use enums, like Text(L10n.Intro.title), but when I do that the environment operator is overriden by the scheme settings language.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("introTitle") //this works
        Text(L10n.Intro.title) //this doesn't
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["en", "ja", "pt"], id: \.self) { localeIdentifier in
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: localeIdentifier)) //this gets ignored, and only the scheme settings language is previewed
                .previewDisplayName(localeIdentifier)
        }
    }
}

internal enum L10n {
  internal enum Intro {
    internal static let title = NSLocalizedString("introTitle", comment: "")
    internal static let title2 = "introTitle" //this also doesn't work
  }
}
```

In *Localizable.strings* I have:

//english

`"introTitle" = "Welcome!";`

//japanese

`"introTitle" = "ようこそ!";`

//portuguese

`"introTitle" = "Bem-vindo(a)!";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred approach would be to use `Text("introTitle")`, but if you want to use enums for your localised keys, you have to declare it like this

```
internal enum L10n {
  internal enum Intro {
    internal static let title = LocalizedStringKey("introTitle")
  }
}
```

and then you will be able to use it like this:

```
Text(L10n.Intro.title)
```

In your code `title` is of type `NSLocalisedString`, `title2` is a `String`, but you need a `LocalizedStringKey` to pass into Text initialiser.

Comment: Awesome! It works! :) I thought it would work with the Text(verbatim: ) that accepts a String, but that doesn't work either. Anyways, your solution looks good. Thanks!

Comment: The reason that I want to do like this is because it's not best practice to write strings directly into the code. If you have some mistake in your string (like a typo or the actual key changes later) the compiler won't warn you and you might not notice it until it's too late. I actually use [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) to help me automatically generating this for me.